# Can we transfer part of some states owned by one node in Corda

Tags: corda

I am new to Corda, My question is that I have a stock State

Name: XYZ LTD,
Amount: 100, 
unitPrice:10

owned by PartyA, now If I want to transfer part of these stocks lets say 
amount:10 of the stocks, I am able to transfer that amount but then the input state will be consumed and what will happen to the remaining "90" stocks. If i query now PartyA will have no states left and PartyB will have the 10 stock states I have transferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, for that you'd use `Fungible states`. please refer the `finance model` [here](https://docs.corda.net/financial-model.html). You'll understand how it works. Corda follows a UTXO Model, so your state which has amount 100 will be consumed and 2 output states will be Created, one with amount 10, which will have owner as the counter party and the other with 90 amount i.e. the change, which you'll be owner of. Refer [Cash State](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/finance/contracts/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/Cash.kt) on how a Fungible state should is implemented.

Comment: Thank you, Is there a java example for this also? One more question if a party registers multiple stocks with same name lets say PartyA had "XXY" stocks of amount: 10, now they have added new with same name but amount: 5, so the balance should be 15 right? So this Fungible states will merge automatically making it a single state that can be used for input?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a java example for the same. I think you mean when a party issues multiple `stocks` it will not automatically be merged, It's not automatically merged you'll have to do that. check how it's done for cash and you'd be able to do it for your own custom fungible state.

Comment: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/finance/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/workflows/GetBalances.kt this is how it's done for cash. you get all the states then add them up